# put all figures one by one in a section

Tags: floats

I have met a simple problem.
Why my figures do not exhbit in the same section?

The code is,

```
\section{Figures}
\begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=7in]{gr}
        \caption{IR}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[width=7in]{jd}
    \caption{Cyc}
\end{figure}
```

But they turn up in different sections.

Comment: `[!h]` makes it highly likely that all figures go to the end of the document as it specifies the figures can not be placed at the top or bottom of a page or on a page on their own (latex usually warns and changes it to `ht`)  use `[htp]` and put `\clearpage` before the next section

Comment: Even using [htp] you would need to add a \clearpage at the end of the section to prevent them from winding up in the next section.

Comment: And I also want to adjust my figures to be best fit so that each page can fill as many figures as possible. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: You could increase \topnumber (2) and \bottomnumber (1) to fit more floats on the page.  You could also increase \topfraction (.7) and \bottomfraction (.3).  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020?s=1|0.0000#39020

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)